# Angular 2 How to Position an Element Relative to Another Element

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, I need to absolute position an element relative to another element. In jQuery this can be done using jQueryUI .position() https://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/position/

I've attempted to create an Angular 2 directive but can't find a way to reference the target element (which could be anywhere on the page) to get top/left/width/height values.

Also, my understanding is that DOM manipulation should be avoided in Angular 2. Can this position functionality be achieved without using nativeElement?

The goal is to be able to create an overlay on top of any page where help/hint text can positioned on top of elements. Note that the page is responsive. This is an example of the desired effect.

[image: help overlay]

Comment: Can one component be a child of another and position that way, via CSS? DOM manipulation should be avoided, yes.

Comment: I'm not sure. I updated the question with: The goal is to be able to create an overlay on top of any page where help/hint text can positioned on top of elements.

Comment: Did the answer give you enough to go on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough implementation that needs more work! Note that this is implemented in an Ionic 2 environment.

**Overview**

Create an "introduction" component that the contains overlay and tooltips/hints. I chose to open this component as an Ionic 2 popover (Ionic will auto add the overlay). Pass relative elements as parameters to the introduction component. Create a directive that absolute positions an element relative to another element (on the page). Sprinkle with scss.

Important: In my case, there are images on the page that take time to load. Position data was incorrect until I waited for the images to load. This is the same in jQuery and is solved by wrapping commands in:

```
$(window).load(function() {
});
```

For now, I have a timer that simply delays opening the introduction page.

**my-position.ts**

This directive sets top/left of an element relative to another reference element (on the page).

```
import { Directive, Input, OnInit, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Inspired by jQuery position: https://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/position/
 */

@Directive({
    selector: '[my-position]',
    host: {
        '[style.position]': '"absolute"',
    }
})
export class MyPosition implements OnInit {
    @Input('my-position') of: any;
    @Input('my') myInput: string;
    @Input('at') atInput: string;
    @Input('offset') offsetInput: string;

    my: string[];
    at: string[]
    offset: string[];

    constructor(
        private element: ElementRef,
        private renderer: Renderer
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {

        if (this.of.nativeElement) {

            let top: number;
            let left: number;

            // Default inputs.
            if (!this.myInput) {
                this.myInput = 'top left';
            }
            if (!this.atInput) {
                this.atInput = 'top left';
            }
            if (!this.offsetInput) {
                this.offsetInput = '0 0';
            }

            this.my = this.myInput.split(' ');
            this.at = this.atInput.split(' ');
            this.offset = this.offsetInput.split(' ');

            // Get reference element position.
            let rect = this.of.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();

            // Set new top/left values.
            left = rect.left + parseInt(this.offset[0]);
            top = rect.top + parseInt(this.offset[1]);

            // Adjust top/left values for on element position.
            if (this.at[0] == 'center') {
                left += rect.width / 2;
            }
            if (this.at[1] == 'center') {
                top += rect.height / 2;
            }

            // Position element.
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'top', top + 'px');
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'left', left + 'px');
        }
    }
}
```

**introduction.html**

Add a tooltip/hint to the introduction page. Add my-position directive and pass the relative element as a parameter. Add additional position parameters (as needed).

```
<div class="hint" [my-position]="hintRef1" my="left top" at="left top" offset="0 105">This is an app hint!</div>
```

**introduction.ts**

Get hintRef1 element parameters in constructor.

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    private viewController: ViewController
) {
    // Get elements (passed as parameters from page) to use as references (to position hints).
    this.hintRef1 = navParams.get('hintRef1');
    this.hintRef2 = navParams.get('hintRef2');
    this.hintRef3 = navParams.get('hintRef3');
}
```

**home.html**

Add name to reference elements (must be camel case) e.g.

```
<div #hintRef1 ...
```

**home.ts**

Get reference elements on home page (to pass as parameters).

```
// Pass position reference elements to introduction popover.
@ViewChild('hintRef1') hintRef1;
@ViewChild('hintRef2') hintRef2;
@ViewChild('hintRef3') hintRef3;
```

Pass reference elements as parameters to introduction page.

```
let popover = this.popoverController.create(IntroductionPage, {
    'hintRef1': this.hintRef1,
    'hintRef2': this.hintRef2,
    'hintRef3': this.hintRef3
    }, { cssClass: 'introduction' });
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding this as a separate answer because it does something different than the original answer, and I think both could potentially be useful to anyone who sees this in the future.

Apologies for the haphazard state of [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/R6qN2e86swBInsVGscJF?p=preview), @Aydus-Matthew. It's kinda been thrown together.

The key part to this is that I've created an injectable `overlay` class that can be used anywhere we want to turn on/off the overlay, or need to check the status of the overlay within the app.

This allows us to use the `[class.my-class]` attribute style on the tooltip to add a conditional style to show the tooltips.

```js
@Injectable()
export class Overlay {
  public IsVisible: boolean = false;
  
  public Toggle(): void {
    this.IsVisible = !this.IsVisible;
  }
}
```

Then use it in the tooltip component like this:

```js
import { Overlay } from './overlay';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-tooltip',
  template: `<span [class.visible]="overlay.IsVisible">{{ Message }}</span>`,
  styles: ['span { position: absolute; display: none; color: white; font-weight: bold } .visible { display: block } '],
})
export class Tooltip {
  @Input()
  public Message: string = "";
  
  constructor (private overlay: Overlay) {  }
}
```

Hopefully this helps you get to the right implementation you need to solve your problem :)

Comment: Helpful to consider this alternative implementation. Still overly complicated trying to align elements due to our complex design. Doing this in jQuery would have been simple.

Comment: Also, many elements on my page are in position relative containers. This causes tooltips not to display properly on top of the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/oB6QJzncNbMAe1sIfVQ8?p=preview

What you should do is create a component specifically for your overlay, and then add that to any components you wish to have a message on:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-tooltip',
  template: `<span>{{ Message }}</span>`,
  styles: ['span { position: absolute; }']
})
export class Tooltip {
  @Input()
  public Message: string = "";
}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-basic-component',
  template:`<div>
                <my-tooltip [Message]="toolTipMessage"></my-tooltip>
        
                Here is a block of text that I want to annotate
            </div>`,
  styles: ['div { position: relative; }']
})
export class BasicComponent {
  toolTipMessage: string = "USEFUL INFO";
}
```

The tooltip component has an exposed message string and a `<span>` element. The `<span>` is placed using `position: absolute` on the CSS and from there you should be able to configure the usage to fit your needs.

Comment: This approach makes sense. The tooltip html is simply part of the page html. However, I can't see a way of using this approach and achieving an overlay effect. Have updated the question to include an example image.

Comment: Aaah, I see. In that case I would implement it using a conditional class on the tooltip component. When active, it gets a style that gives it a high z index and makes it `display: block`. Hidden when no class applied. Does this make sense? I'll try to write up an example when I'm back at my computer

Comment: I like the idea of adding tooltips directly to element html. it makes them easy to position. However, my understanding is that to create the dimmed effect that the tooltips need to be in the same container element. The container element would cover the whole page with css opacity e.g. opacity: 0.5. But obviously this leads to the same problem -- how to position an element relative to "any" another element.

Comment: I've added another answer instead of changing this one. I hope it seems closer to what you're trying to do :)